# Excel - How do I drag down a formula but make it reference horizontally

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Basically this is my formula:

```vbs
=Calibration!BK60+Calibration!BK61+Calibration!BK64
```

And when I drag it down I want it to change to

```
=Calibration!BL60+Calibration!BL61+Calibration!BL64
```

and not

```vb
=Calibration!BK61+Calibration!BK62+Calibration!BK65
```

I am having trouble adjusting an index formula to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, all of which involve feeding the row number into an index or offset type function. My solution would look like this:

```
=LET(colOffset,ROW()+62,INDEX(Calibration!$60:$60,colOffset)+INDEX(Calibration!$61:$61,colOffset)+INDEX(Calibration!$64:$64,colOffset))
```

You would need to adjust `ROW()+62` to whatever is needed based on the row where your formula starts. You want it to be 63 for the first formula because column 63 is `BK`. If you don't have access to the `LET()` function, you can also use this similar but technically slower formula:

```
=INDEX(Calibration!$60:$60,ROW()+62)+INDEX(Calibration!$61:$61,ROW()+62)+INDEX(Calibration!$64:$64,ROW()+62)
```

All we're doing is locking a row reference then pulling a value from that row in a column based on what row the formula is in.

Comment: I have honestly tried using this, I just can not wrap my head around it, the value I get is 0 when I add the formula in with ROW(Calibration!BK60).

I forgot to mention maybe but the values I pull from a different sheet, maybe that is why?

Comment: The `ROW()` function shouldn't reference where the data is, it should reference where the *formula* is. If you put the formula in row 1 of some other sheet, then you want to use `ROW()+62` because: `ROW()` with no arguments defaults to reference the cell where it is so, in this case, it'll be `1` BUT you want *column* 63 (because that's `BK`) so we add `62`. If your formula is in row 12, you want to use `ROW()+51` because that will be `12+51` which is, again, `63`. As you copy / paste the formula down, the value of `ROW()` will increase by 1 which will move the column reference over by 1.

Comment: @Andrei I just double-checked to make sure I wasn't missing something and no, it doesn't matter if the data is on another sheet. You'll need to change the references in the `INDEX()` functions so it'll end up looking like this (if your formula is in row 1 of some other sheet): `=LET(colOffset,ROW()+62,INDEX(Calibration!$60:$60,colOffset)+INDEX(Calibration!$61:$61,colOffset)+INDEX(Calibration!$64:$64,colOffset))`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it works now.